# How do I highlight an NSStatusItem button programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos, menubar, nsstatusitem

I want to emulate the behaviour of the control centre in macOS (11.0) Big Sur.

I know that `NSStatusItem.button.highlight(true)` can be used to set the highlight of a menu bar button. However, when I try to highlight the button by adding `NSStatusItem.button.highlight(true)` to the selector function of the `NSStatusItem.button`, it doesn't work.

How would I go about highlighting the button programmatically so it works similarly to the control centre in macOS (11.0) Big Sur?

[image]